# Generating dependent strictly stationary random processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity

for some nonlinear prediction experiments I'd like to generate a nonlinearily dependented, strictly stationary process. Does anyone know a resource explaining how to do this? One idea would be to define joint probabilities distributions f(x1, ..., xn) from which I sample data at every time step and to adjust the probabilities to my liking. If markov chains are strictly stationary then I could also define transition probabilities P(a|b, c, ...) and create these processes that way.

Any idea?

edit (adding my comment):
By "nonlinearly dependent" I mean that the optimal predictor (in the mean square sense) of a process {x_n} given solely past observations/using solely random variables x_k with k

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "nonlinearly dependent" processes?

Comment: By "nonlinearly dependent" I mean that the optimal predictor (in the mean square sense) of a process {x_n} given solely past observations/using solely random variables $x_k$ with $k < n$, is a nonlinear function f of these $x_k$, i.e. there exists a nonlinear function $f(x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}, \cdots)$ such that $E((x_n-f(x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}, ...))^2) < E((x_n - g(x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}, ...)^2)$ where g can be any linear function. $E$ denotes the expected value. The optimal predictor is only linear when one is dealing with a gaussian process. So I guess I only have to generate conditional probabilities tha

Comment: I am not sure what the policy on stackexchange is on pushing one's thread. I am still interested in an answer :)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers.